# I have an error when I logout from admin "Trying to get property 'id' of non-object" using Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am trying to logout from admin but unfortunately, I face error:

> Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

How to fix this error?

```
public function index(){
   $user_permission = Users_Permissions::with('user')
                       ->Where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
                       ->paginate(5);     
   return view('index',compact('user_permission'));
}
```

Comment: Can you post your error log?

Comment: use `auth` middle ware this function and before get `id` check you have `dd(Auth::user())`

Comment: please check https://flareapp.io/share/Rmrn4Nmz#F47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is clear. When you log out, then `Auth::user()` is null. so there is no `id` . You can solve the issue like this.

```
public function index()
  {
   if (Auth::check()) {
      $user_permission = Users_Permissions::with('user')->Where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)
     ->paginate(5);     
     return view('index',compact('user_permission'));
  } else {
     // The condition when no user logged in
     // For an example
     return redirect('login'); // This is just an example
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For that, use try & catch in every function, and use auth middleware for specific routes while you are working with auth users.

so that specific routes are required to use auth, so you don't need to check in every function. auth is always present.

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function () {
       Route::get('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    });
```

or else you can use middleware in a controller too,

```
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->middleware(['guest'])->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because after logout you don't have user ID, so in this situation the User is null, and you want to get the if from null object. you can change this part of code like below

```
Users_Permissions::with('user')->Where('user_id',Auth::user()->id ?? 0)
```

then you pass the error. you can put every number or `null` in query based on your needs.